# List all available function prototypes from within C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers, function-prototypes

Is there any way within a C or C++ program of getting information on all the functions that could be called? Perhaps a compiler macro of some sort? I know that there are programs that could take in source files or .o files and get the symbols or the prototypes, and I suppose I could just run those programs within a c program, but I'm curious about maybe returning function pointers to functions or an array of function prototypes available in the current scope, or something related?

I'm not phrasing this very well, but the question is part of my curiosity of what I can learn about a program from within the program (and not necessarily by just reading its own code). I kind of doubt that there is anything like what I'm asking for, but I'm curious.

Edit: It appears that what I was wondering about but didn't know how to describe very well was whether reflection was possible in C or C++. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: you can call billions of functions from c/c++ program, do you want them all?

Comment: i see only curious.... be specific what you want to ask.

Comment: No. Take a look at your standard library your OS provides.

Comment: What you seek is reflection, and C++ doesn't have it yet. It is, however, a candidate for future C++ standards.

Comment: @Quentin: I'm terrorized of what the committee would come up with given that C++ lacks a decent metaprogramming language but only provides a template-based one with some hackery bolted on.

Comment: @6502 come on, it's not *that* terrible. Or did it drive me completely nuts ? I do quite like angle brackets now. Anyway, updates are on their way. Thingies like `constexpr` really help already.

Comment: @Quentin: if you think C++ support for metaprogramming is decent then it simply means you never saw a decent one. Using SFINAE or the pathetically complex overload resolution rules as conditionals? using recursion for loops? No functions? No data structures whatsoever? Are you serious?? Doing real metaprogramming in C++ is more or less like doing real programming in brainf*ck.

Comment: @6502 `Are you serious??` Nope ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The language doesn't support [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) yet. However, since you are looking for some sources of information, take a look at the [`Boost.Reflect`](http://bytemaster.bitshares.org/boost_reflect/index.html) library to help you add reflection to your code, to a certain extent. Also, look at [`ClangTooling`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html) and [`libclang`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX.html) for libraries that let you do automated code-analysis.

Answer (score 4):

C and C++ have no way to gather the *names* of all the functions available.

However, you **can** use macros to test standards (ANSI, ISO, POSIX, etc) compliance, which can then be used to guarantee the presence of each standard's functions.

For example, if `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` is defined, you can (usually) assume that functions specified by POSIX will be available:

```
#ifdef _POSIX_C_SOURCE
/* you can safely call POSIX functions */
#else
/* the system probably isn't POSIX compliant */
#endif
```

**Edit**: If you're on a Linux system, you can find some common compatibility macros under `feature_test_macros(7)`. OS X and the BSDs should have roughly the same macros, even though they may not have that manual page. Windows uses the `WINVER` and `_WIN32_WINNT` macros to control function visibility across releases.

Answer (score 1):

No.

C++ meta-programming power is weak don't include any form of reflection. You can however use tools like [gcc-xml](http://gccxml.github.io/HTML/Index.html) to parse a C++ program and export its content in a easier to analyze format.

Writing your own parser for C++ to extract function declaration is going to be a nightmare unless you only need to do that on your specific project and you're ready to cut some corners.